# Insert values from several textboxes into one column but creating a new row for each textbox value

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a C# program to insert data into a SQL Server database. The database has a column and of course multiple rows can be created with data insert. In my Winforms program I have several textboxes that get data from another table, each textbox gets different data. I want to insert data from each textbox into the same column. However, I need each textbox value to go into its own row. Like this

```
ColumnName
-------------------
Value from textbox1
Value from textbox2
```

This is the code I have. The problem is that it inserts the values from the 2 textboxes in the same column like I want but in the same row.

This is the code:

```cs
string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();

_ = TextBox1Text;
_ = TextBox1Text ;

String commandText = "INSERT INTO SQLTableName (ColumnName) VALUES (@ColumnName)";

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);

    cmmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.Text);

    cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox1.Text + ' ' + TextBox2.Text;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this done?

**EDIT:**

I modified the code as suggested in the comments and answer. However, when it enters the data into the database it saves the value from textbox1 into one row, but the value from textbox 2 is being saved twice one in each row.

```
String commandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (ColumnName)Values(@ColumnName)";
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con)
    cmmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.Nvarchar, -1);
    cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
    cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
    cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Assuming the actual column data type is `varchar(n)` rather than the deprecated `text` data type, specify that type and column max length, like `cmmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);`

Comment: Hello, the data type on the database for that column is nvarchar(Max)

Comment: Then specify `NVarchar` instead of `Text`: `cmmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);`.

Comment: I changed it. However, when it enters the data into the database it saves the value from textbox1 into one row, but the value from textbox 2 is being saved twice one in each row.

Comment: My comments were about the parameter mistake, not the other coding problems. Add the current non-working code to your question.

Comment: This is the block of code i am using to insert the data: String commandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (ColumnName)Values(@ColumnName)" if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open){SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con) cmmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.Nvarchar, -1); cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox1.Text; cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox2.Text; cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}

Comment: I edited your question with the information from your comments. The new code will not save the textBox2 value twice so I suspect the problem lies with code you have not shared.

Comment: I found the problem it was due to this line of code cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery inside a try/catch block I had at the end of the code to show a message box when saved successfully or failed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the line

> `cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox1.Text + ' ' + TextBox2.Text;`

with the following:

```
cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value =  TextBox2.Text;
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hello, it worked by entering each textbox value into the same column but different row for each value. The only problem I'm having is that it enters each value twice, so its creating 4 rows every single time, when it should only have 2 rows. How can I fix that?

Comment: Thank you guys, the edit to my code that you provided worked like a charm, the issue I was having was due to a try/catch I had at the end of the code, that had another ExecuteNonQuery statement in it, so It was entering the last value twice.